# Need help on ghost computers and deploy active directory

Tags: active-directory, windows, ghost

Is it possible to set up pc to join domain, then ghost it to many pc.

Is there any side effect for both original pc and all ghost pc?

Comment: do you have a w2k8+ server available? If so you could use WDS to deploy, if you have r2 available you can multicast the deploys for faster deploys.

Answer (score 1):

Not feasible. Ghost should have a functionality to join upon creation. But if you ghost a working integrated computer they would share the same active directory identity-  with disastrous side effects. First one to renew AD password would throw the others out.